# disabling ImageButton in Windows Mobile 5.0

Tags: c#, windows, mobile

i would like to disable my ImageButton, but when i use Enabled property and set it on false button simply disappear and i would like to make him "gray"(i hope You know what i mean...). What is best solution for this?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "gray" version of the image and when you want to disable the button change to this image, and then check in your click event wheather or not you consider your button to be enabled.